# CS50 - mario pyramid/ the last hash isn't printed

Tags: c, cs50

I can't understand why the last hash of the last line isn't printed. If I print this code, it looks like this:

```
./mario
Height: 3
  #  #
 ##  ##
###  ##     < --- last hash piece is missing!
```

I think I already declared to print it by saying `else if (3*h - j == i.)`.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int h;
    do
    {
        h = get_int("Height: ");
    }
    while (h < 1 || h > 8);

    for (int i=0; i < h; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < h + h+1; j++)
        {
            if (h - j -1 > i || h + h - j +2 < h - i  )
            {
                printf(" ");
            }
            else if (h==j || h+1 == j)
            {
                printf(" ");
            }

            else if (3*h - j == i)
            {
                printf("#");
            }
            else
            {
                printf ("#");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: The inner loop makes `h + h + 1` iterations, but the last line should consist of `h + h + 2` characters. Assuming you actually meant to have a gap of two spaces, and not one, in the middle.

Comment: Suggestion: Don't `#include <cs50.h>` (which is a non-standard header, including a massive amount of other C headers) . Include the headers you need instead.

Comment: Also, please don't flag both C and C++. Pick one.